# Scaling infinite value ranges to a finite interval

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, data-visualization

I want to display measurement values in a histogram-like fashion. The user can chose between various measurements, which are very different in nature. For instance, method complexity typically yields values between 1 and 20. In contrast, the date of the last change of a source file yields unix timestamps, which are very large numbers.

I know how to trivially scale those value ranges into the size (height) of my histogram, but this approach yields very confusing results sometimes. For instance, when all values are very large, all bars in the histogram are almost of the maximum height, and the difference can hardly be perceived. In this case, it probably would be favorable to subtract a constant close to the minimum value from all values to get a more distinctive visualization.

Other measurements yield values in very small value ranges, like 1 to 3. In this case, the visualization is very misleading, since 3 would be scaled to the maximum possible size, and 1 to the minimum possible size, and the difference looks huge, although it isn't. In this case, it probably would be favorable to add a constant to all values, to reduce the difference between the histogram bars.

Are there any general approaches to this problem that on the one hand ensure distinctiveness and on the other hand avoid misleading visualizations? Any algorithms that fit arbitrary series of values nicely into a given interval?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `{x_i}` be your set of values, and then `min = min{x_i}` , `max = max{x_i}`.

You can now normalize every value on the set in the [0,1] interval, with:

```
x_i = (x_i - min) / (max - min)
```

As you can easily see, the max element will be 1, the min will be 0, and the itnermediate values will keep their proportion. You can scale this a bit adding a constant if you don't line the 0 value in the histogram, then the min will be `alpha` and the max `1 + alpha`.

In general, you can map every set in the interval `[a,b]` doing:

```
x_i = a + (x_i - min) * ( b - a ) / (max - min)
```

Comment: This method really doesn't work for infinite range as the title of the question would suggest. Either OP doesn't understand his own requirements or the title is phrased poorly.

Answer (score 2):

One approach I've used in the past is to take `exp(lbound(log(min(data))))` and `exp(ubound(log(max(data))))` as my range, choosing whatever log base fits my aesthetic.